# How can I format a Bitlocked SSD in Ubuntu, so I can install Windows 10 on it?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, partitioning, ssd, bitlocker

After dual-booting with Ubuntu 18.04, my Windows 10 main drive got locked by Bitlocker. There is just no way to get the recovery key.

I downloaded GParted, and it shows my Bitlocked drive there. I created a bootable Win 10 USB. Now the only thing I'm not sure of right now, is how to completely format the Bitlocked drive, so I can do a fresh Win 10 installation there.

I can see the option: "Format to" in GParted, but I'm not sure to what format I should format my disk (maybe NTFS?).

Can somebody give me some tips on that?

Answer (score 0):

NTFS is the correct choice. It will erase the encrypted file system created by BitLocker.

After reinstalling Windows, you might need to rebuild your Grub bootloader, as the Windows installation might erase it.